# Mediawiki: Invalid Edit Token

Tags: php, http, wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

I use the API with HTTP POST to create a wiki page in a Mediawiki (1.14):

1. I require an edit token
2. It works, I get a fresh token (example: d96d72fae5e6c43b0b9f63d82ace366)
3. I send the HTTP POST for creating a new site with my new token (sth. similar to "d96d72fae5e6c43b0b9f63d82ace366+\"
4. I get an error message **"Invalid Token"**

I don't understand why I get this message, because I send a freshly created token in my POST request.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you URL-encode the terminating characters of your token? You have to convert the `+\` to `%2B%5C`. Your POST request should look something like (minus the line breaks):

```
action=edit&title=Talk:River%20Otters
&section=new
&summary=Otters%3F
&text=Anyone%20see%20any%20otters%20lately%3F
&watch
&basetimestamp=2009-06-22T13:52:41ZZ
&token=d96d72fae5e6c43b0b9f63d82ace366%2B%5C
```

Comment: i get +\\ at the end of my token. Should i leave out the trailing second slash?